# Alpine: persistent disk mounted to /media/sda even though fstab has /media/usb

Tags: vmware, alpine-linux

I'm having some issues with Alpine Linux, running in "diskless" mode on ESXi. I have configured it following the [instructions in the wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_on_VMware).

Here's the content of the fstab file:

```
/dev/cdrom  /media/cdrom    iso9660 noauto,ro 0 0
/dev/sda /media/usb vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

(This was configured exactly as per instructions in the wiki)

However, at boot, the `/dev/sda` disk is mounted on `/media/sda`, and nothing gets mounted on `/media/usb`. The consequence is that my local backup isn't restored.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

1. re-mount `/dev/sda` to `/media/sda` as rw
2. edit fstab to use `/media/sda` instead of `/media/usb`
3. re-run `setup-lbu` to use `sda`
4. re-run `setup-apkcache` to use `/media/sda/cache`
5. run `lbu ci`

Background and longer answer:

Apparently alpine mounts the available partitions (and r/o at that) before `/etc/fstab` is parsed. And in case an fstab entry overlaps with one of the partitions, it fails to mount.

I have not been able to find the exact spot where it happens in alpine source code, but found that the behaviour is mentioned here: https://oscillate.gr/words/router-pt2/

Quote from that link:

> For example if the formatted device is sda1 mount it under /media/sda1. It seems that alpine’s initrd scripts mount every available filesystem under /media using the device name, ignoring your fstab. This kind of makes sense since fstab is not available in the pre-boot environment. So in order to avoid any further complications I recommend that we stick to that convention.

The [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536291/388074) by Francesco Colista cannot really be used when booting from cdrom iso as was my case (VirtualBox) and I assume the OP's as well (ESXi).

However, it seems that `setup-lbu` detects the available mounts in `/media` directory, so the simplest way is to use the automatic mount and run `setup-lbu` to specify `sda`  as the lbu storage device.

Example:

```
alpine:~# setup-lbu
Enter where to store configs ('floppy', 'sda', 'usb' or 'none') [usb]: sda
```

The same applies to `setup-apkcache` which can also be configured to use `/media/sda` mount.

> #### Note
>
> If you start from a clean boot, just configure the mount this way from the start and `setup-alpine` will pick it up for the initial setup
>
> ```
> # mount /dev/sda /media/sda
> # grep /dev/sda /proc/mount >> /etc/fstab
> # setup-alpine
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option passed by the bootloader.

If you have syslinux (the default bootloader used by alpine), check 
 `boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg`  and modify the `alpine_dev` option from usbdisk to sda like this **example**:

```
serial 0 9600
timeout 20
prompt 1
default grsec
label grsec
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-grsec
    append initrd=/boot/initramfs-grsec alpine_dev=sda:vfat modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod,usb-storage quiet console=tty1,38400 console=ttyS0,9600
```

Since is an example, adapt it according with your settings (especially the kernel and initrd).

.: Francesco